# Mega Menu Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, megamenu

I've tried to look for a solution for this but can't seem to find it anywhere.

I'm looking to stylise the drop down for the sub > sub category. So the hierarchy would be -

Root > sub category > sub category > sub category

At the moment it works up until Root > sub category > sub category but beyond that it just lists the sub category under that without recognising that there's a category head above it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can it be because of this?

```
    private function getCMSMenuItems($parent, $depth = 1, $id_lang = false)
{
    $id_lang = $id_lang ? (int)$id_lang : (int)Context::getContext()->language->id;

    if ($depth > 3)
        return;
```

In file modules/blocktopmenu/blocktopmenu.php

My 2 cents,
pascal

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's about the mega menu actually and I think the code below needs to be added to but don't know how to add an extra ul and li 


    foreach ($children as $child)
                               // echo "<pre>";
                               // print_r($child);
    $smart_megamenu .=  $this->getCategory((int)$child['id_category'], (int)$id_lang, (int)$child['id_shop']);

    $smart_megamenu .= '</ul>';
   }
   $smart_megamenu .= '</li>';
  }
              
                return $smart_megamenu;
 }